# Find method returns cache data in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, caching, orm, entity-framework-4.1

Is there any difference between

```
var c = context.users.Find(100)
```

and

```
var c = context.users.FirstOrDefault(o=>o.id = 100)
```

I don't know why `Find` method returns cache data.

Answer (score 0):

Find() will avoid a trip to the database if an object with the specified key is already attached to the data context.